# Will RIA Services SL Client Library and Tooling work agains ADO.NET Data Service / OData?

Tags: silverlight

At MIX it was announced that WCF RIA Services supports OData Endpoint on the server now.
But is there also a good way to consume data from an OData Server in the WCF RIA Services Tooling also now?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Brad Abrams' blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2010/03/16/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-odata-services.aspx), RIA Services can expose their data as OData, have a look.

Comment: Sorry, my question was about CONSUMING not exposing OData with RIA Services.